# how to display socket's data sent from server in two output fileds in browser according to the requirements?

Tags: php, javascript, sockets, websocket

i am designing a chat program in php using websockets. In client side i want to display chats and online users in two different output fields. 
Since chat messages and online users are sent from server using same socket_send() method then how to distinguish on the client side  that if server has sent the online users or chat messages , when i recieve the socket's data on client side , so that i can display them in two different output fields.

Hope you will understand what i want to say.
I am using javascript on client side.

Comment: You need to put something in the application protocol that distinguishes them.

Comment: Assuming you are using the JSON.stringify and JSON.parse methods on the client side, you can add the appropriate property name to the string, and you're good to go. For example, you can preface a list of user names with "users:" and an actual chat message with "msg:" (or whatever). I guess the point is, you can do whatever you want, but that might be the simplest solution if you're using the JSON object in JS.

Answer (score 0):

The WebSocket connection in your case is something like the air in the real world. WebSocket messages correspond to sounds. When people make sounds, these sounds are transmitted via the air to other people's ears.

However, in order to make us understand what other people's sounds mean, we developed something that can be called a communication protocol. We developed words and gave them a pronunciation. So, the emitter-people are able to transform whatever they think into sounds. The receiving people are able to transform these sounds back into sense.

So far, your client and server have air, the WebSocket, in between them. And you can make sounds (sending messages). But so far, both are missing a communication protocol, a common understanding. You have to provide that. No way around. You will realize that this may become quite a complex task.

Still, it is fun to play god and design transformation rules between meaning, sounds ("messages" in your case), and the other way round.

So, go ahead, invent a protocol. This is what the others were saying. You should come up with certain object types, such as `User` and `Message`, you will assign properties to a message, such as `sender` and `recipient`. Then, you will most likely encode these objects in some form, put them into messages and send these messages around between client and server.

Both, client **and** server need to be aware of your fundamental object types and need to know how objects are encoded in these messages.